# iOS + Swift 2: Dynamic height in UITableViewCell doesn't work with an empty view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

This is my problem. I'm using a custom UITableViewCell as a Cell prototype with identifier "cellidentifier" into the UITableView. In this UITableViewCell I have added (in Interface Builder) an empty UIView into contentView's cell that I call "bubbleView", It has a connection @IBOutlet and I added constraint top = 0, bottom = 0, leading = 0 and trailing = 0.

In the controller (which inherit from UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate), into the viewDidLoad function I added this lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...
   self.mytable.delegate = self
   self.mytable.dataSource = self
   self.mytable.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
   self.mytable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   ...
}
```

Then, I implemented methods of UITableViewDelegate in this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellidentifier") as! myCustomCell!
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = myCustomCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"cellidentifier")
    }
    let myNewView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, randomWidth, random Height))
    cell.bubbleView.addSubview(myNewView)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count   
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

With that code, I can add myNewView into the cell, but the cell not adjust to the real height according the myNewView height, for example if myNewView height is 134, my custom view cell always return 44 in height. I added the layoutIfNeeded property as some tutorials says but It doesn't work. Anyone have a solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

Does your empty view have a height constraint? If you are just pinning the bubble view to the superview's edges, I don't think that is enough for Auto Layout to figure out how tall the cell should be.

Also, for your prototype cell, go to the Size inspector. How is your Table View Cell configured there? Having it configured as "default" vs Custom may or may not resolve the problem.

If you want the cell to truly autosize itself, you will definitely need to provide enough constraints so that a height can actually be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: this is a topic about constraints. If you notice in Interface Builder, you need to be very clear with constraints, so assign top, bottom, leading and trailing are ambiguos for empty view. Then, the solution is add constraints to myNewView according your needs (in my case on top, width and height) and set height constraint to view container (cell.bubbleView) in reference with myNewView:

```
//Create my view
let myNewView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, randomWidth, random Height))

myNewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

//Assign top constraint according with container (cell.bubbleView)
let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myNewView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.bubbleView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
cell.bubbleView.addConstraint(pinTop)

//set width constraint of myNewView
let pinWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myNewView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: myNewView.frame.size.width)
cell.bubbleView.addConstraint(pinWidth)

//set height constraint of myNewView
let pinHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myNewView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: myNewView.frame.size.height)
cell.bubbleView.addConstraint(pinHeight)

//set height constraint of container according the myNewView plus top and bottom space
let pinHeightView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.bubbleView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: myNewView.frame.size.height+20)
cell.bubbleView.addConstraint(pinHeightView)

cell.bubbleView.addSubview(myNewView)
```

and finally don't forget configure UITableView to make height cell dynamically.

```
self.mytable.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
self.mytable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

And it works perfectly